# Classes ending with Post are not forming Hibernate 4 proxies

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I find that after upgrading to libraries to use 2.4.2 jackson-datatype-hibernate4 that most of the classes are being proxied correctly. But I also find that below classes show content as null in rendered json even though there is data.

```
UserPost
GroupPost
UserGroupPost
```

If I use projections then it is rendered / if I disable Hibernate proxies and enable JsonIgnoreProperties on "hibernateLazyInitializer" and "handler" , then also it is rendered.

Is their a possibility that Entities whose name is ending with **Post** are causing some kind of mixup ? I tested about 50 models and only find this happening with these Entities and are configured exactly like others and therefore am thinking in this direction ..

So when I go to /userGroupComments/12/userGroupPost I get below output, where UserGroupPost -> 1.* -> UserGroupComment

using Spring Data Rest , JPA latest builds(1.8.0.M1)

OUTPUT:

```
{
  "content" : null,
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/app/userGroupPosts/4"
    },
    "userGroupComments" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/app/userGroupPosts/4/userGroupComments"
    },
    "userPost" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/app/userGroupPosts/4/userPost"
    }        
  }
}
```

Links are correctly getting rendered but not the content. Entities are annotated with @AccessType(Type.PROPERTY) from org.springframework.data.annotation.AccessType

Comment: It seems proxies are being formed but SDR is not rendering content for these entities ..

Comment: I created a small project with UserPost as entity name and it works but somehow in this entity it is not creating. So should not be a generic issue .. can you point when content is set as null in SDR

Comment: I have commented Hibernate 4 proxies and started using JsonIgnoreProperties on hibernateLazyInitializer explicitly which works